# Airflow DAG dynamic structure

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I was looking for a solution where I can decide the dag structure **when the dag is triggered** as I'm not sure about the number of operators that I'll have to run.

Please refer below for the execution sequence that I'm planning to create.

```
           |-- Task B.1 --|                  |-- Task C.1 --|
           |-- Task B.2 --|                  |-- Task C.2 --|
  Task A --|-- Task B.3 --|---> Task  B ---> |-- Task C.3 --|
           |     ....     |                  |     ....     |
           |-- Task B.N --|                  |-- Task C.N --|
```

I'm not sure about the value of N.

Is this possible in airflow. If so, how do I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar in the past, I wrote a DAG which read from a YAML file which defined what tasks to create.

My situation was that the number of tables that I was extracting data from could change every week, instead of re-deploying the DAG to production every time I needed to add a new table I pointed the DAG to a YAML file which described which tables to extract. Every time a new table came along I would simply edit the YAML file with the new table details.

I think it gets a bit trickier if an upstream task needs to be run first which then determines how many downstream tasks to run like in the following - but similar - question:

[Generating dynamic tasks in airflow based on output of an upstream task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116819/generating-dynamic-tasks-in-airflow-based-on-output-of-an-upstream-task)

Comment: We achieved this by fetching the configuration from the database and created tasks as per the configuration...